# Python: Converting python2 to python3

Tags: python, openstreetmap

I am trying to use

https://github.com/iandees/mongosm/blob/master/insert_osm_data.py

this package. It seems like it is written in Python2. I have converted all the way to `next(context)`. However, I am getting `name 'long' is not defined`.

Is there any way that I can define this somewhere? How can I define 'long' and I have no idea what this is for even for Python2 Script (which worked fine somehow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

long() is basically renamend to int() in Python 3.
Please see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0237/ for details.

So, either do a search of long and replace with int, or define it

```
long = int
```

somewhere at the beginning of your file.

Answer (score 1):

You should convert all code to Python3

https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=Converting+python2+to+python3
https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html